# Populate QPlainTextBrowser from within a function

Tags: python, qt

I have used Qt Designer to ceate a GUI for a Python script.

When I try to use

```
Ui.plainTextBrowser.insertPlainText("anythong")
```

the `plainTextBrowser` does not populate with text until the function is complete and then it does so all at once. How can I get it to populate in say, real time? I am trying to use it to update the user of the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Call processEvents() function from your app (QtGui.QApplication):

```
app.processEvents()
```